# How to truncate author list in refernces in RevTex4-2

Tags: bibliographies, citing, revtex, author-number

I'm using RevTex4-2 for an article with lots of references. The default is to list all authors. I instead need to truncate the author list in references: when there are more than 3 authors A, B, C, D, ..., it just displays A, B, C, et al. How to do this?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico longbibliography, because I need titles displayed.

Comment: The file `longbibliography.bst` does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Is it available online?

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I mean I'm just using the default `\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}` of revtex4-2. No explicit bibliography style is necessary.

Comment: The style will be `apsrev4-2.bst`